# Variable is nil at launch but I want it to be 0 swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have a function that shows the position (moved) of a scrollView. At launch the position is nil then it changes as you move. When you go back to page 1 the position is 0. I can't change it so the launch number is not nil then as the item scrolls it scales to show page position (it doesn't matter if it starts with 0 or 1 as long as its not nil and goes up incrementally) Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
var screenPage: Int?
var screenPos: Int?
var screenPlaceFinal: Int!

func walkthroughDidScroll(position: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat) {

      // getting the page number from the scroll position. First page loads as nil so want it to be zero.


      // position when it starts is nil but I want it to be 0
      if let screenPage = screenPage {
      screenPlaceFinal = Int(((position / view.bounds.size.width) + 1) - 1)

      } else {
        //show an alert ot something else
        self.screenPlaceFinal = 0
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just initialize `screenPos` as 0? No optional required.

```
var screenPos: Int = 0
```

It will start as 0 and can never be `nil`, because it's not an optional.

Comment: Thank you. I am an imbecile.